# How do I combine two files without overwriting any data in python?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, cat, shutil

I need to concatenate two files, one which contains a single number and the other which contains at least two rows of data.  I have tried shutil.copyfile(file2,file1) and subprocess.call("cat " + file2 + " >> " + file1, shell=True), both things give me the same result. The file with the single number contains an integer and a newline (i.e. two characters) so when I bring the two files together the first two characters of file2 are overwritten instead of just added to the end.  If I do it through the shell using "cat file2 >> file1" this does not happen and it works perfectly.

Here is what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
from subprocess import call

f.open(file1)
f.write('2\n')
np.savetxt(file2,datafile,fmt)
call("cat " + file2 " >> " + file1, shell=True)
```

So instead of getting:

```
2
data data data ...
data data data ...
```

I get:

```
2
ta data data ...
data data data ...
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue but it is very frustrating. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `file1` in `a` mode and simply writing `file2` to `file1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't flushed f. "2\n" is still in the file buffer and overwrites the other data after cat completes when f is eventually closed. But there Is a better way to do this. Reading the numpy docs [savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), you can pass in a file handle. Numpy can use the existing file handle to write its data. No need for a second temporary file.

```
import numpy as np

with open(file1, "w") as f:
    f.write('2\n')
    np.savetxt(f, datafile, fmt)
```

Comment: THIS. This is EXACTLY what I wanted! I totally gave up on trying to write the integer then writing the data and figured it would be easier to concatenate the two files! Thank you! I would upvote if I could but my reputation isn't high enough.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried closing `file1` first?

```
 f.close()
 np.savetxt... Etc
```

Answer (score 0):

To append `file2` to `file1`, you could use `'a'` file mode as [@krookik suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459760/how-do-i-combine-two-files-without-overwriting-any-data-in-python#comment28857061_19459760):

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

with open(file1, 'w') as f: # write file1
    f.write('2\n')
# `with`-statement closes the file automatically

# append file2 to file1
with open(file2, 'rb') as input_file, open(file1, 'ab') as output_file:
    copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

Your code doesn't work because it might be missing `f.flush()` or `f.close()` after `f.write('2\n')` as [@beroe suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19459937/4279) i.e., when the `cat` command appends to `file1`, its content is not flushed from memory to disk yet, `'2\n'` is written later (when the file is closed implicitly on the program exit) and therefore  it overwrites content written by `cat`.